# Were they trying to kill off Klinger?

Tags: character, mash

In the two parter 'Fade out, fade in' in *MASH* we see that Klinger enlists the services of a 'lawyer' to get him a section 8. Although this fails, **out of universe, was this an attempt, at least initially, to 'kill off' the character of Klinger?** Are there indications that Farr wanted to leave the show at this point?

Comment: Forgive me for stating the obvious, but wasn't Klinger *always* trying to get a discharge, in various ways?

Comment: @Walt yes it's just it struck me that we said goodbye to Ferret Face and this seemed like it was a good chance for Klinger to leave also

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.  This interview doesn't specifically state the timeframe that he's discussing, and I don't recall when that episode aired, but Farr does discuss that he asked for a raise and the studio's typical response was to write a character out of a show rather than give in to the actor's demands.

But, at the same time, Walt is correct in that for the **majority** of the show, Klinger was trying his best to get a Section 8 dismissal.  At some point, after a discussion with Col. Potter, he stopped trying to do that.

The interview is here (and should start up at 29:08, where Farr talks about asking for the raise).

[Jamie Farr interview](https://youtu.be/W7B0kfHar-g?t=27m45s)